# Server Unexpected Shutdown

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-server-2008, event-log, windows-server

If you have a Windows server that has an Unexpected Shutdown and there is nothing in the logs (no power failure, critical events or hardware failures), and no memory dump for blue screen then is the only reasonable conclusion that somebody came in and pressed the reset button on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  With a sudden loss of internal power, it will cease operation without storing anything, so there will be no log, memory dump, etc. indicating an event or cause.  You can't conclude anything unless you have a means to rule out all other potential causes.